# In python packaging perspective, is there any difference between "import numpy" or from "numpy import functionnames"?

Tags: python, numpy, import

I have to package libraries into distributions and I was wondering whether there was any difference between importing all the functions from the numpy modules

```
    from numpy import pi, cos, sin, tan, arcsin, arctan, arctan2, exp, sqrt, array, polyval, polyfit, ndarray
from numpy import linspace, rad2deg, zeros, argmax, argmin, log, max, min, mean, loadtxt, delete
from numpy import float as nfloat
from numpy import append as nappend
from numpy import max as nmax
from numpy import min as nmin
from numpy.linalg import norm
```

or just doing the most commong way

```
import numpy as np
```

and then calling each function as

```
np.functionname
```

Someone told me that when installing the library, in the package, only the effectively used functions will appeare. But still, even if true, it is not clear to me which kind of advantage should bring.

What do you think?

Tnx!

Comment: There is no immediate difference. But if you are running unit tests and want to patch / mock the function you will have to do it for the first case in the importing module and for the later case in the `numpy` module.

Comment: I think an advantage when using import numpy as np is to prevent namespace pollution. See also this post https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function

Answer (score 1):

The difference in my opinion is, that the code may be more readable. That in itself is an advantage. The header may be very clustered with imports, but your code can be more easily read. By others and yourself.

Comment: To experienced `numpy` users the `np.sin` approach is clearer.  It is compact, yet clearly identifies the source of the function.  This is especially valuable when functions with similar names occur in various packages (or even the base python).